# What possible escape characters exist for SQL INSERT statements?

Tags: sql, sybase

I remember seeing a source with 4 escape sequences listed for `INSERT` statements, but I lost the source and wasn't sure if those were all of the possible sequences.

I know `''` and `\n` are special.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Data, Name) VALUES ('single''quote', 'new\nline');
```

What are all of the possible special sequences for SQL `INSERT` statements?

Comment: What flavor SQL implementation? What version? Different flavors vary wildly.

Comment: @NicholasCarey It's Sybase, not sure what version.

Comment: The only ones in SQL server that I know of are the doubling up of single quotes and a [backslash immediately before an end of line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221996/73226). Quite likely that one goes back to Sybase days.

Comment: There are lots of special sequences that vary on the SQL db, version and also underlying database table/field character encodings. Also you may want to avoid having to escape if possible and just use parameterized queries.

Comment: @VenomFangs I agree that parameterized queries is a good practice. I'm trying to figure out cases I want to test, and I'm also interested in what special sequences are valid just for general knowledge.