# SQL Server not escape \ CR LF

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column type `text`. In this column save for parameters, one per line.

My problem if parameters ends with "\" because path name, when saving data, SQL Server remove CR LF, leaving two parameters per line.

#### Example

Save

```
Path=C:\Transfer\
Outher=Yes
Outher1=No
```

Recover

```
Path=C:\Transfer\Outher=Yes
Outher1=No
```

With have SQL Server not clear "CR LF" after "\"?

#### Aditional info

```
create table TEST ( Ini text);

insert into TEST values 
(
'Path=C:\Transfer
Outher=Yes
Outher1=No
');

insert into TEST values 
(
'Path=C:\Transfer\
Outher=Yes
Outher1=No
');

select * from TEST;
```

#### First Insert return

[image]

#### Second Insert return

[image]

Comment: can you add a little more detail, what are you trying to do? import/export data?

Comment: Someone should fix the grammar issues in this question.

Comment: You are seeing this in SQL Server Management Studio? What if you copy/paste the output from SSMS into Notepad++ and have `Show all Symbols` activated... Are you still seeing missing CR/LF?

Comment: @TT add image for Notepad++

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you really want to be using `varchar(max)` instead of `text` datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this is by design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207007.aspx) to allow for better readability of long strings in SSMS (or whatever client).

> Breaks a long string constant into two or more lines for readability.

You can get around it by putting a space after your `\`

```
select 'Path=C:\Transfer\ 
Outher=Yes
Outher1=No'
```

or

Explicitly concatenating the new line separately

```
select 'Path=C:\Transfer\'+ '
Outher=Yes
Outher1=No'
```

or

Doubling up on everything (thanks @TT)

```
select 'Path=C:\Transfer\\

Outher=Yes
Outher1=No'
```

See [this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221996/726127).

Comment: -or- doubling the terminating backslash apparantly.

Comment: @TT doubling the backslash, for me, leaves one slash in but still eliminates the CRLF.

Comment: Escaping the last backslash 'Path=C:\Transfer\\  otherwise the parser thinks you are escaping the new line.

Comment: @Brad I see. I saw that Martin suggested that in his answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221996/243373). I thought I'd mention that.

Comment: @TT, ah I see, the difference is he also doubled the newlines. In which case, yes, that will work!