# SQL insert query deletes characters from file url

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

If I want to send a SQL insert query from my java app:

```
INSERT INTO `addInformation` (`id`, `info`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'D:\Info\javaapp\ClothesPickerProject\ClothesImages');
```

It will be saved in database like this:

```
D:InfojavaappClothesPickerProjectClothesImages
```

So it deletes those oblique bars and I don't know why. The very same thing happens if I send the same query from the inside of phpmyadmin. What can I do in order to avoid this mess?

Comment: `'\'` symbol must be quoted (doubled), use ``INSERT INTO `addInformation` (`id`, `info`) VALUES (NULL, 'D:\\Info\\javaapp\\ClothesPickerProject\\ClothesImages');``. Or use `'/'` in paths.

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134016/how-to-escape-back-slash-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more slash

```
INSERT INTO `addInformation` (`id`, `info`) VALUES (NULL, 'D:\\Info\\javaapp\\ClothesPickerProject\\ClothesImages');
```